# Animate button inside custom adapter for listview

Tags: android, listview, animation, adapter

I made a `ListView` with a custom adapter with my own layout, and on this layout there is a text view, a button and three image buttons that are at first with `setVisibility.GONE`
I am trying to animate this button for when the user clicks on it, it changes its position from right to left to give space for the three image buttons.

The problem is, the only item in which the animation is working is the last item on the list. I want the animation to work in all of the items.

Here's the code for my `adapter`:

```
public class ListaAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
private ListView lista;
private Button btnAbrir;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private ObjectAnimator animation;


public ListaAdapter (ArrayList<String> list, Context context, ListView a) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = a;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
parent) 
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
}

TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textoItem);
listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

final LinearLayout btnLayout = (LinearLayout) 
 view.findViewById(R.id.btnLayout);

relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

btnAbrir = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAbrir);

ImageButton btnNaoSei = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnNaoSei);

ImageButton btnAceitar = 
(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAceitar);

ImageButton btnNegar = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnNegar);

animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btnAbrir,"x",200);

btnLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

btnAbrir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            btnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           animate();
        }
    });



    return view;
}

private void animate()
{
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.start();
}
}
```

And this is my custom_list.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:background="@color/compras_barra">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnNaoSei"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/compras_barra"
                android:contextClickable="false"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/a12" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnNaoSei"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="NÃO SEI"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:background="@color/compras">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnAceitar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:background="@color/compras"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/a11" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnAceitar"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="ACEITAR"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:background="@color/compras_texto2">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnNegar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/compras_texto2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/a10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:text="NEGAR"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAbrir"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/a09"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textoItem"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/compras_texto2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you need to adopt the following method and create a `ViewHolder` so that your adapter will know each element of each row in the `List`

The last UI element of the row only animates because this the only last known id of components for your `Adapater` when he was creating the `View`s in your `List`. So it will animates for the last row elements

You have to add `ViewHolder` nested `class` inside your `Adapter` and declare your UI components. Use `setTag` and `getTag` methods inside the `getView`

Overall you have to create your `adapter` things like this in `getView`

```
public class SListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private String[] seCtnColors;
    private List<Subscription> item;
    private ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View row;

    public SListAdapter(Context c, List<Subscription> subscriptions)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.row,R.id.rowNameTV);
        this.context=c;
        this.item = subscriptions;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        row = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        initAdapterUI();
        setAdapterDataset(position);

        return row;
    }

    private void initAdapterUI() {

        viewHolder.animatedGifViewHol = row.findViewById(R.id.row_animated_gif);
        viewHolder.alertBarVerticalViewHol = row.findViewById(R.id.alertBarVerticalView);
        viewHolder.firstNameTVHol = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowNameTV);
        viewHolder.phoneNumberTVHol = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowNumberTV);
        viewHolder.switchStateTVHol = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.switchStateTV);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    private void setAdapterDataset(int position) {
        mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        mainViewHolder.alertBarVerticalViewHol.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        mainViewHolder.switchStateTVHol.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        mainViewHolder.firstNameTVHol.setText(item.get(position).getFirstName());
        mainViewHolder.phoneNumberTVHol.setText(item.get(position).getNumber());
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        View animatedGifViewHol;
        View alertBarVerticalViewHol;
        TextView firstNameTVHol;
        TextView switchStateTVHol;
        TextView phoneNumberTVHol;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Mariana :)